# Cannot import sklearn in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn import svm
```

I am getting the following error while importing `sklearn` modules.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/iterative.py in <module>()
  9 
 10 from scipy.sparse.linalg.interface import LinearOperator
---> 11 from scipy.lib.decorator import decorator
 12 from .utils import make_system
 13 

ImportError: No module named decorator


ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e938be4cf50b> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn import svm

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/__init__.py in <module>()
     54     # process, as it may not be compiled yet
     55 else:
---> 56     from . import __check_build
     57     from .base import clone
     58     __check_build  # avoid flakes unused variable error

ImportError: cannot import name __check_build
```

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error time ago, it is caused because either the machine doesn't have the scipy package installed, or it has the wrong distribution (depending on the architecture or OS).

If you have `pip` in your computer try installing scipy with:

```
sudo pip install scipy
```

If you have it already try upgrading or reinstalling the package.

**Edit:**

Following the solution suggested by @erip, you can create a virtual environmentand test the solution keeping your python global site-packages directory clean:

```
virtualenv test # This creates a folder with the virtual env
source test/bin/activate
pip install scipy
pip install sklearn
```

To deactivate and remove the virtual env:

```
deactivate
rm -r test # Remove the folder
```

Comment: Personally I wouldn't recommend `sudo pip install` anything and would opt for a `virtualenv`.